# MS Powerpoint Addin : Insert Slide from Base 64 Powerpoint addin API does not carry over the original formatting of the slide

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers, powerpoint-addins

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.presentation?view=powerpoint-js-preview#powerpoint-powerpoint-presentation-insertslidesfrombase64-member(1)

I'm currently using the above Powerpoint Addin API to insert slides from base 64. But the inserted slide doesn't seem to carry over all the original formatting from the original PPTX file(from which the base 64 string was created). Any ideas on why the original formatting wasn't applied during insert?

```
PowerPoint.run(function (context) {
                return context.sync.then(function(){
                    context.presentation.insertSlidesFromBase64(base64String),{
                        formatting: 'KeepSourceFormatting'
                    };
                    return context.sync()
                })
            });
```

Comment: Please show your code, so we can try to reproduce.

Comment: @RickKirkham I have added the code in the post. The issue doesn't seem to be happening to all files. I'll be happy to share to the file with which the issue seems to replicate in case you need it.

Comment: I recommend that you try to reproduce this problem in the [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) tool. Install the tool in the file that's giving you problems. You might get an informative error message.

Comment: @RickKirkham I tried adding slides from my file to a new presentation using the script lab sample but even the script lab sample is not taking the source formatting of that particular file.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Consider creating an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).